# Component finding in graph BFS

Tags: c++, pointers, graph, components, breadth-first-search

I have written the program in which I am making the adjacency list of a graph, which is working perfectly:

```
class graph {
private:
    Q q;
    int v;   //no of vertixes
    struct node* array;             //array of vertixes
public:
    ...
};
```

Now I want to find the number of components in that graph. I have written this code, but it gives me a segmentation fault error at run time when it try to run `findingcomponent()` function.

```
void findingcomponents()
{
    int compcount = 0;
    int noOfcomp = 0;
    node* curr;
    for (int i = 0; i < v; i++)
    {
        curr = array[i].head;
        if (curr->next != NULL)
        {
            while (curr)
            {
                //while loop for the connected nodes traversel
                while (curr)
                {
                    compcount++;
                    //loop for inner loop traversal and for enque data
                    if (curr->next->visited != true)   //if the next loop of this parent loop is not visited.
                    {
                        q.EnQ(curr->next->nodeno);
                        curr->next->visited = true;
                        curr = curr->next;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        curr = curr->next;
                    }
                }
                curr = array[q.deQ()].head;
            }
            noOfcomp++;
        }
    }
    cout << endl << "There Are : " << noOfcomp << "components in this graph.";
}
```

***Additional infos:***

The nodes are defined as follows:

```
struct node {
    int nodeno;
    bool visited;
    struct node* next;
    struct node* head;
};
```

I use a `Q` class for managing a queue.

```
class Q
{
private:
    node* front;
    node* roar;
public:
    ...
    int deQ()
    {
            node * temp = new node;
            if (front == NULL){
                    cout << endl << "\t Queue is Empty";
                    return NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                    temp = front;
                    front = front->next;
                    return temp->nodeno;
            }
    }
...
};
```

Comment: And don't you think providing the exact error would help answer the question? Anyway, you're accessing many pointers without checking they're non-zero first, so I suggest fixing this, then going over it with a debugger if the problem persists.

Comment: should i provide the full code?

Answer (score 0):

**First problem:**

When you look at the head of the adjacency list, here:

```
    curr = array[i].head;
```

you can't be sure that the list is not empty (i.e. head is nullptr).
So when you write on the next line:

```
    if (curr->next != NULL)
```

You might dereference a null pointer, which is undefined behaviour and hence might trigger a rutime error (when you're lucky). This happens whenever you have a node which has no edge.

**Next problem:**

In the inner `while` loop, you can be sure that `curr != nullptr`.  This time dereferencing is ok, but you can't be sure that `curr->next` is not null.  So when you write

```
if (curr->next->visited != true)
```

you might again dereference a null pointer and have undfined behaviour (for example a segfault, if you're lucky).

With the dataset that you've provided, this happens at the first node:  the loop goes through the adjacency list, and on the last element the error is triggered.

**Other potential problem**

I have not analysed in depth your algorithm, as there is important code missing.  But it is not clear to me how it is ensured that all enqueued values are dequeued, and that `q.deQ()` is not called when not called when the queue is empty.

Well, with the additional code provided, in your `deQ()` you return 0 (`NULL`) if the queue is empty.  But you also return 0 when encountering the node 0. So you don't process correctly the end of the queue, risking to loop for ever.

Therefore you have to change this function to:

```
int deQ()
{
    node * temp = new node;
    if (front == nullptr) {
        cout << endl << "\t Queue is Empty";
        return -1;   // <======!!!!  Normally you should declare a constant for this 
    }
    else {
        temp = front;
        front = front->next;
        return temp->nodeno;
    }
}
```

**Wrapping it together: correction of your function**

```
void findingcomponents()
{
    int compcount = 0;
    int noOfcomp = 0;
    node* curr;
    for (int i = 0; i < v; i++) {
        curr = array[i].head;
        if (curr == nullptr) {  // make sure you don't hit isolated nodes
            cout << "isolated node";
        }
        else            if (curr->next != nullptr) {
            while (curr) {       //while loop for the connected nodes traversel
                while (curr) {
                    compcount++;
                    //loop for inner loop traversal and for enque data
                    if (curr->next != nullptr && curr->next->visited != true)   //!!!!!!if the next loop of this parent loop is not visited.
                    {
                        q.EnQ(curr->next->nodeno);
                        curr->next->visited = true;
                    }
                    curr = curr->next;     //!!! this was called at the end of the if, and in an else:  just call it systematically.  
                }
                int nodeid = q.deQ();   //!!! here deque and  
                if (nodeid == -1)       //!!! check if a node was found in the quue
                    curr = nullptr;     //!!! if not 
                else curr = array[nodeid].head;
            }
            noOfcomp++;
        }
    }
    cout << endl << "There Are : " << noOfcomp << "components in this graph.";
}
```

Please verify however if the number of components is correct.  I suspect that you increase the counter in a wrong manner.  But you have now 3 hours left to address it.

Comment: where can i send you the full code dear? @Christophe 
i am really stuck and just 4 hours remains,

Comment: The easiest way would be to post the relevant code in the question ([MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).  It's not a good practice, but If you post a link to a github repository I could have a look at well, but I have only 20 minutes left...

Comment: i don't know how to use github dear..
:(

Comment: Please take a look on it

Comment: 7   //no of nodes
8   // no of edges
2 0
3 1
1 5
4 7
6 7
5 0

Comment: Do you have the full set of data you're using and that is causing the error ?  Can you paste it as well ?  I can't reproduce with this data...

Comment: it is a simple data set but everytime it gives me error

Comment: ok ! I could reproduce it:  your code didn't call the function when executed online :-)  It breaks right at the start with what I described as "Next problem" in my answer

Comment: Which funtion , u mean function for finding compoments is not calling?

Comment: @Feci I've edited my answer.  THe probelm is exactly what I've described initially.  I've completed with some solutions.  For convenience, here the full code: http://pastebin.com/AVgPWHdu - as said: verify if you count well the components. Good night !

Comment: thanks alot brother @christophe, 
all set with pointers, 
it still giving the wrong component , i don't know why,  :( can u last time see that.?
i want 
no of components in graph, 
and their sizes, 
no of components in graph is 4, and their sizes are 3,2,4,5